# How to test twilio send sms with mockery?

Tags: php, unit-testing, twilio, phpunit, mockery

I am writing a test case to send a sms using twilio sdk in php in a laravel application.
I created a mock of the Client class, and I expect that the client will receive the messages then create methods and return a response.

Initialy, I wrote the following test, which return the error `Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_0_Twilio_Rest_Client::getAccountSid(), but no expectations were specified` 
From the execution stack of the test, I see that the methods seems to be called on the real twilio SDK, which is not what I think it should do.

```
1) Tests\Unit\Services\Sms\TwilioAdapterTest::given_a_valid_phone_number_when_sending_sms_then_it_should_return_a_message_id
Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_0_Twilio_Rest_Client::getAccountSid(), but no expectations were specified

/home/aduhaime/Documents/projets/arm_sms/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010.php:128
/home/aduhaime/Documents/projets/arm_sms/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010.php:276
/home/aduhaime/Documents/projets/arm_sms/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Client.php:606
/home/aduhaime/Documents/projets/arm_sms/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Base/BaseClient.php:231
/home/aduhaime/Documents/projets/arm_sms/app/Services/Sms/TwilioAdapter.php:13
/home/aduhaime/Documents/projets/arm_sms/tests/Unit/Services/Sms/TwilioAdapterTest.php:31
/home/aduhaime/Documents/projets/arm_sms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:173
```

**The implementation**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services\Sms;

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class TwilioAdapter implements SendsSms
{
    public function __construct(private Client $client) { }

    public function send(string $from, string $to, string $message)
    {
        return $this->client->messages->create($to, ['from' => $from, 'body' => $message]);
    }
}
```

**Failing test**

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Services\Sms;

use App\Services\Sms\TwilioAdapter;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class TwilioAdapterTest extends TestCase
{
    private function getTwilioClientMock($mockFunction)
    {
        return $this->mock(Client::class, $mockFunction);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function given_a_valid_phone_number_when_sending_sms_then_it_should_return_a_message_id()
    {
        /** @var \Twilio\Rest\Client $twilioClient */
        $twilioClient = $this->getTwilioClientMock(function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('messages->create')->andReturn(json_encode(['sid' => '1234567890']));
        });
        $adapter = new TwilioAdapter($twilioClient);
        $response = $adapter->send('+1234567890', '+554569999', 'Hello World');
        
        $this->assertNotNull(json_decode($response)->sid);
    }
}
```

After some time, I found a way to make the test pass:

**Passing test**

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Services\Sms;

use App\Services\Sms\TwilioAdapter;
use Mockery\MockInterface;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\Http\Response;

class TwilioAdapterTest extends TestCase
{
    private function getTwilioClientMock($mockFunction)
    {
        return $this->mock(Client::class, $mockFunction);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function given_a_valid_phone_number_when_sending_sms_then_it_should_return_a_message_id()
    {
        /** @var \Twilio\Rest\Client $twilioClient */
        $twilioClient = $this->getTwilioClientMock(function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('messages')
            ->shouldReceive('getAccountSid')
            ->andReturn(MessageList::class)
            ->shouldReceive('create')
            ->shouldReceive('request')
            ->andReturn(new Response(200, '{"sid": "SM1234567890"}'));
        });
        $adapter = new TwilioAdapter($twilioClient);
        $response = $adapter->send('+1234567890', '+554569999', 'Hello World');

        $this->assertNotNull($response->toArray()['sid']);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to make that kind of test?

I feel like I should not have to know what method are called internally by the sdk and write `shouldReceive` for getAcountSid() and request().

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). That error message with stack trace is text, and should be included as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

> $mock->shouldReceive('messages->create')

Mockery has support for ["mocking Demeter chains"](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html), but it will assume the chain is composed of *method* calls, so this sets up the mock to respond to this:

```
$this->client->messages()->create(...);
```

However, what you're trying to mock is this:

```
return $this->client->messages->create(...);
```

Note that `->messages` is a *property access*, not a *method call*.

This may be clearer if you spell that out with some intermediate lines:

```
$client = $this->client; // 1
$messages = $client->messages; // 2
$result = $messages->create(...); // 3
return $result;
```

- Line 1 is going to return your mock client object, so that's great.
- Line 2 is going to access *a property* on that object - maybe in the real Client that's a real property, maybe it's a virtual property implemented with `__get`, no way to tell here.
- Line 3 is going to call the `create` method *on whatever line 2 found*.

So what we actually want is to set the `messages` property on the mock client, to itself be an appropriate mock.

The tricky part is knowing what class or interface to mock. Digging into [the source code of `Twilio\Rest\Client`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/main/src/Twilio/Rest/Client.php), it looks to me like this is the (virtual) property we want to mock:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @property \Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList $messages
 * ...
 */
```

Which would look something like this:

```
// Set up a mock
$mockMessageList = Mockery::mock('\Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList');
// Assign it to the `messages` property of the mock client
// this should over-ride the virtual property that the real client would use
$twilioClient->messages = $mockMessageList;
// Now we can set up expectations directly on the 'messages' mock
$mockMessageList->shouldReceive('create')->andReturn(json_encode(['sid' => '1234567890']));
// And inject the client into the adapter we're testing
$adapter = new TwilioAdapter($twilioClient);
```